# How to get value from input without html tags using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, input

.val() get text with html tags?
Maybe .text(), but how to do this correctly?

Comment: why do you want the HTML tags? Anything you could possibly gain from doing this can probably be done in Jquery without getting the actual HTML. Explain what you actually want to do and we can probably help better,

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementById(elementId); // or just another HTML DOM element
var text = el.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
```

might do something close to what you want.

*EDIT:* This is what it does on Stack Overflow:

```
document.getElementById("portalLink").innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "")
```

in Chrome's Console yields

```
"
            Stack Exchange
        "
```